# ArcPy UpdateCursor fails when adding a transform to SHAPE@XY due to type error

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I have a Feature class with 285k point features.  I am running this code on it:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FeatClass, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + transformX,row[0][1] + transformY]])
```

transformX and transformY are floats.  This code has worked previously but fails with the error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

There are no gaps in the ObjectID, so apparently this is saying one of the objects has geometry of NoneType?  Does that even make sense?  If so, how do I identify the problem?

Comment: You'll probably want to print the OBJECTID of the feature that yields that error so you can manually check it. Knowing the OBJECTID allows you also to create a cursor for just that feature and run some tests and gain some insights about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have features in your feature class without geometry. `"SHAPE@XY"` returns `(None, None)` when a feature has no geometry. As @MarceloVilla suggested, you can print out the `OBJECTID` of the features without geometry if you're interested knowing these.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FeatClass, ["SHAPE@XY", "OID@"]) as cursor:
    for (x, y), oid in curs:
        if x == None or y == None:
            print "null geometry in oid {}".format (oid)
        else:
            row = ((x + transformX, y + transformY), oid)
            cursor.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: How is it possible for a feature to have no geometry?  I suspect that there was geometry previously, and a user somehow was able to remove the geometry without removing the entire record.  I'm not sure how that works because if I were to select a feature either in the table or on screen and delete it, the entire feature would be gone.

Comment: The geometry is a bit like at attribute (not quite that simple, but it's similar).  You can have a <NULL> attribute (ie and attribute with no value).  Similarly, you can have a feature with no geometry (at least in some databases).